# How to write the list to file?

Tags: python

I am unable to write the result of the following code to a file

```
import boto3
ACCESS_KEY= "XXX"
SECRET_KEY= "XXX"
regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
for region in regions:
  client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
  addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
  #f = open('/root/temps','w')
  for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
    with open('/root/temps', 'w') as f:
      if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
         print eip_dict['PublicIp']
         f.write(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
```

This results in printing the IP's but nothing gets written in file, the result of print is :

```
22.1.14.1
22.1.15.1
112.121.41.41
....
```

I just need to write the content in this format only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
    with open('/root/temps', 'w') as f:
      if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
         print eip_dict['PublicIp']
         f.write(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
```

You are re-opening the file for writing at each iteration of the loop. Perhaps the last iteration has no members with 'PrivateIpAddress' in its dict, so the file gets opened, truncated, and left empty. Write it this way instead:

```
with open('/root/temps', 'w') as f:
    for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
        if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
            print eip_dict['PublicIp']
            f.write(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
```

Comment: ahh got it, instead of `w` i need `a`

Comment: @PythonFreak no, that's not correct. The 'a' will work, but it doesn't explain why this change doesn't solve the issue unless there's something you haven't told me.

Comment: how to write each ip in separate line?

Answer (score 0):

open file in append mode

```
 with open('/root/temps', 'a') as f:
```

or
 declare the file outside the loop

Comment: yep true,, and how to line break so that in each iteration the IP gets printed in other line

Comment: concat '\n' at end of write